# Problems resolving Jenkins build failure

Tags: ros, jenkins, bloom-release, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to debug a build failure that resulted after pushing a fairly innocuous change to a single source file in my [package](https://bitbucket.org/crl/multisense_ros). The important parts of the build failure are as follows (from the [Jenkins build output](http://build.ros.org/view/Kdev/job/Kdev__multisense_ros__ubuntu_xenial_amd64/lastBuild/console)):

```
14:51:12 ==> Processing catkin package: 'multisense_lib'
14:51:12 ==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/multisense_lib'
...
14:51:36 <== Finished processing package [3 of 6]: 'multisense_lib'
14:51:36 
14:51:36 ==> Processing catkin package: 'multisense_ros'
14:51:36 ==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/multisense_ros'
... 
14:51:40   The dependency target "multisense_lib" of target "multisense_ros" does not
14:51:40   exist.
```

This has not been a problem in that past, and I don't have any problems building this myself (even in a very minimal chroot installation of 16.04). Unfortunately, the prerelease command I would use to try to recreate this issue consistently fails with a "Hash sum mismatch".

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243272/problems-resolving-jenkins-build-failure/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message you quoted is just a CMake warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:103 (add_dependencies):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "multisense_lib" of target "raw_snapshot" does not
  exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

This warning is due to using a newer CMake version and you can ignore it in this case. It will go away once the newer version of `genmsg` is available (https://github.com/ros/genmsg/pull/65).

The actual error why your build fails is the following:

```
/tmp/catkin_workspace/src/multisense_ros/multisense_ros/src/raw_snapshot.cpp:42:45: fatal error: multisense_lib/MultiSenseTypes.hh: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The header can not be found because the include directories are likely incomplete. The package `multisense_ros` correctly depends on `multisense_lib` and uses the include directories (https://bitbucket.org/crl/multisense_ros/src/7cb8c91dbbd1f9a9b082d6f4cdc6cc8214880f43/multisense_ros/CMakeLists.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-10,60). But looking at the package `multisense_lib` package it seems to not export any include directories: https://bitbucket.org/crl/multisense_ros/src/7cb8c91dbbd1f9a9b082d6f4cdc6cc8214880f43/multisense_lib/CMakeLists.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-27,28 I would expect the problem to be fixed if the include directory is exported correctly:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES MultiSense
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge)
```

The referenced job has only four builds so there is not enough history for me to tell when it was actually starting to fail. In order to reproduce this locally you might need to use `catkin_make_isolated`. I assume you use `catkin_make` which will make all packages share the same install location (rather then a per package isolated one). So any other package exporting an include directory which is being used by `multisense_ros` will mask the problem and let you find the header.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2016-09-07**:
Ah, I was thinking the nonexistence of the dependency target was the reason behind the trouble finding the header.

Thanks for the tip with `catkin_make_isolated`. I was able to reproduce and resolve the problem on my machine.

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2017-01-30**:
I haven't seen mention of that CMake warning in any other posts, so I'm posting here to see if there is any other resolution to that issue other than wait for the newer version of genmsg. It would be great to be a "stable" package again.